# Flex items going out of the flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I tried using width property, flex, fle-basis, flex-shrink etc. but nothing seem to work, I cannot pinpoint the mistake. in the code.
Below is the HTML and CSS code:

I am trying to add the code snippet too but its thorwing some error saying add some details so putting the code on the codepen and here is the codepen link

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #444;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  /* font-size: 40px; */
  color: #efb60cf5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-style: italic;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(203, 203, 59, 0.066);
  padding: 10px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: bold;
}
a {
  color: azure;
}
.nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.main-container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.header {
  background-color: #444;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  padding: 30px 40px;
}

.article-header {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  background-color: #444;
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.card {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  height: 400px;
}

footer {
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Practising the flexbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-container">
      <header class="header">
        <h1>This is Flexbox Practice page</h1>
        <nav class="nav">
          <a href="/challange/challenge2.html">Challenge</a>
          <a href="index.html">Learning</a>
          <a href="#">Blank</a>
          <a href="#">Blank</a>
          <a href="#">Blank</a>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <article>
        <header>
          <h2 class="article-header">
            <!-- this is the text I am adding to check the line length Below from -->
            here  I Need to prepare 3 horizontal cards
          </h2>
        </header>
        <div class="cards">
          <!-- Card 1 -->
          <div class="card card1">
            <h3>how was your day</h3>
            <p>this card is to describe how was your day</p>
            <p>In this card I will be putting something related to my day.</p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum
              culpa, vel tempora non, fugiat laudantium itaque, maiores a vitae
              iste minus? Eum, omnis quidem voluptates dicta iure ducimus quas
              magnam!
            </p>
          </div>
          <!-- Card 2 -->
          <div class="card card-2">
            <h3>how was your day</h3>
            <p>this card is to describe how was your day</p>
            <p>In this card I will be putting something related to my day.</p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum
              culpa, vel tempora non, fugiat laudantium itaque, maiores a vitae
              iste minus? Eum, omnis quidem voluptates dicta iure ducimus quas
              magnam!
            </p>
          </div>
          <!-- card 3 -->
          <div class="card card-3">
            <h3>how was your day</h3>
            <p>this card is to describe how was your day</p>
            <p>In this card I will be putting something related to my day.</p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum
              culpa, vel tempora non, fugiat laudantium itaque, maiores a vitae
              iste minus? Eum, omnis quidem voluptates dicta iure ducimus quas
              magnam!
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
      <footer>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2023 By Harsh gaur</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Below is the image too of the container:**
[image]

Comment: Why don't you add the code directly to the question?

Comment: I am unable to add the code thats why I had to add link

Comment: Can you elaborate on your exact problem? Do you want the "How was your day" panels to horizontally fit into the "Here I need to prepare 3 horizontal ..." container?

Answer (score 1):

based on your .cards class u have to include a "flex-wrap: wrap;".this will wrap up the flex area if it overflows.tried it on your code snippet

```
.cards {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: after applying`flex-wrap: wrap;` the cards changed to verticle view

Comment: yes i agree you just needs to add flex wrap

Comment: it did not work but when I changed the main-container width to px from %, it worked fine.